# CopyTable from Hbase 0.90.4 to Hbase 0.94.6 not working

Tags: hbase

I'm trying to copy table from Hbase 0.90 to Hbase 0.04 with this command:

```
$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --peer.adr=ZKHOST:2181:/hbase --starttime=1378252486000 --endtime=1378338886000 --new.name=my_table my_table
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
13/09/04 21:52:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201305141438_0003
13/09/04 21:52:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/09/04 21:52:21 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201305141438_0003_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: ?7805@hbase10.dc.yyy.nethbase10.dc.yyy.net,60020,1378354913021
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HServerAddress.<init>(HServerAddress.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RootRegionTracker.dataToHServerAddress(RootRegionTracker.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RootRegionTracker.waitRootRegionLocation(RootRegionTracker.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:786)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:895)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:797)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManag
```

I have 10 hosts in new the destination system hbase01 to hbase10. The script automatically picks 1 host, but I'm not sure why it is trying to use something like 'hbase10.dc.yyy.nethbase10.dc.yyy.net', that looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes copy table needs to be able to connect to both clusters.  They will need to be RPC compatible.

- 0.90 -> 0.90
- 0.92 -> 0.92, 0.94
- 0.94 -> 0.92, 0.94
- 0.96 -> 0.96

Perhaps export/import can be used to do what you are looking for ?

https://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#export